# external memory vector

Tags: c++, data-structures, stxxl

I am developing an external memory data structure, and I need to put the data into a vector structure that automatically make swapping (maybe using LRU strategy) in order to keep a fixed RAM memory. I have tried the stxxl vector structure, but the problem is that it cannot store dynamic structures like `std::vector`. This doesn't work:

```
stxxl::vector< std::vector<T> >
```

Is there any library of external memory structure that could deal with these kind of elements?

Comment: i dont know what stxxl is but have you tried this "stxxl::vector< std::vector<int> >" ?

Comment: yes, but this generate inconsistent values when I insert a lot of data

Answer (score 6):

Template parameter of `stxxl::vector` is the type of contained items,
but `std::vector` is not a type, its missing it's template argument.

Try e.g. `stxxl::vector<std::vector<int> >`, or create
an enclosing template class around `stxxl::vector` if you want to
parametrize the itemtype of `std::vector`.

**UPDATE**:
After some research, I found this on the **Stxxl: FAQ**'s first page
http://algo2.iti.kit.edu/stxxl/trunk/FAQ.html

> Parameterizing STXXL Containers
>
> STXXL container types like stxxl::vector can be parameterized only
>   with a value type that is a POD (i. e. no virtual functions, no
>   user-defined copy assignment/destructor, etc.) and does not contain
>   references (including pointers) to internal memory. Usually, "complex"
>   data types do not satisfy this requirements.
>
> This is why `stxxl::vector<std::vector<T> >` and
>   `stxxl::vector<stxxl::vector<T> >` are invalid. If appropriate, use
>   `std::vector<stxxl::vector<T> >`, or emulate a two-dimensional array by
>   doing index calculation.

Comment: would have if it was tagged and if mentioned explicitly in your answer

Comment: it looks irrelevant, but ok, I'm replacing it for backward compatibility

Comment: Sorry for arguing , but its completely relevant to answer as per the tags. +1. for the edited answer :)

Comment: I forgot to put the template parameter on the post, my problem is that the implementation of the stxxl::vector can't hold consistent values of dynamic structures

Comment: I mean, it compile but in running time I get some segmentation faults

Comment: That's right, that's why I'm asking if somebody knows an external memory vector library that support dynamic structures as elements.